# jBPM Workbench & KIE Server interaction

Tags: drools, jbpm, kie

I am running 7.0.0.CR2 of workbench and server in a docker container. It looks on first view that they are working perfectly together. However, when I select the tasks tab in the workbench I get the following error:

> Unable to complete your request. The following exception occurred:
>   Can't lookup on specified data set: jbpmHumanTasksWithUser.

This lead me to this bug: https://issues.jboss.org/browse/JBPM-5432

There they are saying that this is caused by a user not having the kie-server role. There is no kie-server role in my installation, there is however a kie-server group, and the user I am using is a member of this group.

Dockerfile and user and role files can be found here:

https://gist.github.com/martijnburger/c9a1072746d94ffe4beff72830e03ca7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe it could be due to a missing login module in your set up, to ensure the role/authentication is passed on to the Kie Server, you need to add a custom login module. Please check this example as reference: https://github.com/cristianonicolai/kie-wb-dev-docker/blob/master/src/main/resources/standalone-full-kie.xml#L379